# Image could not be saved Python

Tags: python, image, blend-files

I create a new image using

```
bpy.data.images.new(name = "MyImage", height = 1024, width = 1024, color = (0, 0, 0, 1), alpha = True, generated_type = 'BLANK', float = False)
```

Then I specify filepath:

```
filepath = bpy.data.filepath[:len(bpy.data.filepath) - bpy.data.filepath[::-1].find('\\')]
# this gives the current blend file filepath but without its name:
# bpy.data.filepath is "C://Users//astre//Documents//MyFiles//untitled.blend"
# filepath would be "C://Users//astre//Documents//MyFiles//"

bpy.data.images['MyImage'].filepath_raw = filepath

bpy.data.images['MyImage'].file_format = 'PNG'
```

But when I try to save it:

```
bpy.data.images['MyImage'].save()
```

**The in the console error occurs:**

```
RuntimeError: Error: Image 'MyImage' could not be saved to 'C:/Users/astre/Documents/MyFiles/'
```

The directory hasn't got restrictions for writing files

I tried using `image.filepath` instead of `filepath_raw` but it doesn't work too.

And with filepath.replace("\\", "/") neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are builtin python libraries like [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for path manipulation.

Don't forget to cast it back to a `str` before using it with the blender API, otherwise it will throw an error.

```
from pathlib import Path
import bpy

folder = Path(bpy.data.filepath).parent
image_filepath = folder / "MyImage.png"

print(image_filepath)
bpy.data.images['MyImage'].filepath_raw = str(image_filepath)
```

You can also do it that way :

```
image_filepath = Path(bpy.data.filepath).with_name("MyImage.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after changing the `filepath_raw`:

```
bpy.data.images['MyImage'].filepath_raw = f"{filepath}MyImage.png"
```